# Pushing on one branch; rejection on another

Tags: git

A few weeks ago I started working with git and I love working with it.

But I'm wondering, why I keep getting rejections when I make a `git push` (the push works, even if I get that error).

I have the following set up:

```
master
 \_ development
     \_ feature/blog*
```

Now I'm working on feature/blog which I created from development.
When I make a `git push` I get the following error message:

```
$ git push
[...]
To [...]@[...]:[...]
   288274e..34c17c3  feature/blogs -> feature/blogs
 ! [rejected]        development -> development (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '[...]@[...]:[...]'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Even if I do a `git pull` it won't work. I also get an `Already up-to-date.` message.

How to prevent that error? I only want to push the current checked out branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you need to tell git what you want to push where.

You can for example say:

```
git push origin HEAD:feature/blogs
```

This will push the current HEAD to feature/blogs on origin.

Then there are a few shorthands:

```
git push origin feature/blogs
```

This will look for a local branch "feature/blogs" and push it to origin as a branch with the same name.

If you simply say

```
git push
```

you do not specify what to push where. Hence git will have to "guess" what you mean. - In your case it just pushed all local branches to branches of the same name on origin.

You can specify what git shall do in this case by setting `push.default`. For example:

```
git config push.default current
```

will tell git to push only the current branch to a branch of the same name.

Have a look at `git help config` and look for push.default for other options.

Newer git versions default to `push.default=simple`, which will generally give you much better feedback.

Comment: Thanks! That makes life more beautiful! :D

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `git push`, git tries to push all the branches that have remotes.  So you did successfully push `feature/blogs`.  `development` failed because you are behind for that remote.  If you `git checkout development` then do a `git pull`, you should get updates for that branch.

Do `git push origin feature/blogs` to only push the one branch.

Since you are only trying to push `feature/blogs`, this message isn't anything to worry about.  Unless the branch that failed to push was `feature/blogs`

I believe that this feature is changing in the newest version of git.  In that `git push` will only push the branch that you are on rather than all of them.